# Cut a string in a string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, image, substring

I have a string that is returned from PHP through AJAX. The string value is like this:

```
<img src="/images/error.png"/>Invalid name`
```

Is there any way to cut the string starting with `<` and ending with `>` ?

I only need the `<img/>` from the string. I do not want to return the only `<img/>` from PHP because the full string is used in another page.

Comment: Will there ever be tags inside the img src that will can be ">"? Will it always start with "<"?

Comment: To "cut" a string by a certain string delimiter, use the `split` method: `string.split("<")`. If this string isn't static, but can contain arbitrary HTML, it is better to use the DOM to parse the HTML and get the part you want.

Comment: How can the string differ?

Comment: This makes me think of http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/464257 ...

Comment: @user829323 `img` always start and end with `<` and `>`

Comment: @Harikrishnan Yes, but will your string contain HTML other than `img` tags?

Comment: @Asad the string is static as i had given

Comment: @Harikrishnan split the string by the delimiter "/>" and remove the first element of the first element will return the inside of the img tag, assuming you do not have /> anywhere else inside the tag for example inside an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What this what you meant? This alerts `'<img src="/images/error.png"/>'`

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUvVJ/)

```
var img = '<img src="/images/error.png"/>Invalid name';
var slice = img.slice(0, img.indexOf('>') + 1);
alert(slice);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [split() method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and add back in the last character.

```
var returnedString = '<img src="/images/error.png"/>Invalid name';
var returnedImage = returnedString.split('>')[0] +'>';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var str = '<img src="/images/error.png"/>Invalid name';
alert(str.substring(str.indexOf('<'), str.indexOf('>')+1));
```

Edit:
If this action is going to be repeated many times, then performance should also be considered.
See 2 versions for each pure JS answer you got so far: the first 3 assume the tag starts at 0 ('<'), the last 3 don't: http://jsperf.com/15512887

I'm now proud of myself even if my answer won't be the chosen one :-)

Comment: +1 `slice` vs `substring` is probably a little in `substring`'s favour as it's designed just for strings, where as `slice` works with all arrays. Split is much slower because it splits the array into two where we only actually care about the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If you explicitly what to get the initial tag only of a string, then:

```
var s = '  <img src="/images/error.png"/>Invalid name';

var tag = '<' + s.split(/\W+/g)[1] + '>';
```

Though for robustness you should do something like:

```
var parts = s.split(/\W+/g);
var tag = parts.length? '<' + parts[1] + '>' : '';
```